# How can I make this vba work the way I need?

Tags: excel, vba

I modified this vba code to generate combinations of six from 10 groups of pairs where only one number of a pair is used for each combination. but I can't get exactly what i want, and there many repetitions of the same combinations and some numbers are not even used in combinations. Can I get a little help to fix this code, please? thanks.
Here is the vba:

```
Sub Combs()
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim g As Long
    Dim h As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim grp
    grp = Range("B1:C10").Value
    Dim arr(1 To 1025, 1 To 10) As Long
    For a = 1 To 2
        For b = 1 To 2
            For c = 1 To 2
                For d = 1 To 2
                    For e = 1 To 2
                        For f = 1 To 2
                            For g = 1 To 2
                                For h = 1 To 2
                                    For j = 1 To 2
                                        For k = 1 To 2
                            i = i + 1
                            arr(i, 1) = grp(1, a)
                            arr(i, 2) = grp(2, b)
                            arr(i, 3) = grp(3, c)
                            arr(i, 4) = grp(4, d)
                            arr(i, 5) = grp(5, e)
                            arr(i, 6) = grp(6, f)
                            arr(i, 7) = grp(7, g)
                            arr(i, 8) = grp(8, h)
                            arr(i, 9) = grp(9, j)
                            arr(i, 10) = grp(10, k)
                                        Next k
                                    Next j
                                Next h
                            Next g
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2").Resize(1025, 6).Value = arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is a sample data:

```
Group1  1   2
Group2  3   4
Group3  5   6
Group4  7   8
Group5  9   10
Group6  11  12
Group7  13  14
Group8  15  16
Group9  17  18
Group10 19  20
```

Comment: `arr` is 10 columns wide but you only export 6 columns. Try exporting all the 10 columns and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, yes when I do what you said, it works, but  I need only 6 columns out of ten.

Comment: The columns you're cutting off are the ones changing. You're seeing repeated values because the part that makes it unique is what you've removed with those cut off columns. To fix this issue, only generate six columns, dont remove any on output.

Comment: Also, a tip for readability. You can combine Dim lines like so: `Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your want to randomly select 6 from 10

```vb
Sub Combos()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim c As Integer, digit As Integer
    Dim b As String, bb As String
    Dim grp, arr(1 To 1025, 1 To 10) As Long, cols

    ' group data
    grp = Range("B1:C10").Value

    For j = 0 To 31
       b = CStr(WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(j, 5))
       For k = 0 To 31
          bb = b & CStr(WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(k, 5))
          i = j * 32 + k + 1

          ' select 6 of the 10 columns
          cols = SixFromTen
          Range("V" & i + 1) = Join(cols, ",") ' show combo
          For c = 0 To 5
              n = cols(c) '
              'Debug.Print j, k, n
              digit = CInt(Mid(bb, n, 1))  ' binary digit
              arr(i, c + 1) = grp(n, digit + 1)
          Next
       Next
    Next

    Range("O2").Resize(1025, 6).Value = arr
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub


Function SixFromTen() As Variant

    Dim num As New Collection, ar(5) As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, tmp As Integer

    For n = 1 To 10
        num.Add n
    Next

    For i = 0 To 5
        n = 1 + Int(Rnd() * num.Count)
        ar(i) = num(n)
        num.Remove n
    Next

    'bubble sort
    For a = 0 To 4
        For b = a + 1 To 5
            If CInt(ar(a)) > CInt(ar(b)) Then
                tmp = ar(a)
                ar(a) = ar(b)
                ar(b) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
   
    SixFromTen = ar
    
End Function
```

Alternatively remove 4 from 10 to leave 6 in correct order.

```vb
Function SixFromTen() As Variant
    Dim num As New Collection, ar(5) As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    For n = 1 To 10: num.Add n: Next

    ' remove 4
    For i = 0 To 3
        n = 1 + Int(Rnd() * num.Count)
        num.Remove n
    Next

    For i = 0 To 5: ar(i) = num(i + 1): Next
    SixFromTen = ar   
End Function
```

Comment: yes, that's what I need really. You changed the code entirely. thanks a lot. The list of group numbers is a nice touch too.

Answer (score 1):

As AcsErno pointed out, the issue is that your program is generating ten columns of digits but the output is only for six columns. Removing four columns results in many repeated combinations because the unique part has been removed in those four columns.

The solution is to only generate six columns, therefore allowing each of them to remain unique. I have rewritten your program to only generate six columns:

```
Sub Combs()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, e As Long, f As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr(1 To 1025, 1 To 6) As Long
    Dim grp() As Variant
    
    grp = Range("B1:C6").Value
    
    For a = 1 To 2
        For b = 1 To 2
            For c = 1 To 2
                For d = 1 To 2
                    For e = 1 To 2
                        For f = 1 To 2
                            i = i + 1
                            arr(i, 1) = grp(1, a)
                            arr(i, 2) = grp(2, b)
                            arr(i, 3) = grp(3, c)
                            arr(i, 4) = grp(4, d)
                            arr(i, 5) = grp(5, e)
                            arr(i, 6) = grp(6, f)
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2").Resize(1025, 6).Value = arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: The upper bound of the array can be reduced from 1025 since we are no longer using as many rows. If you require additional combinations, you can add a third number to any of the pairs.

An Example:

How to input the combination numbers

[image: Sample Data]

```
Sub Combs()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, e As Long, f As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr(1 To 1025, 1 To 6) As Long
    Dim grp() As Variant
    
    grp = Range("B1:E6").Value 'Increasing the width
    
    For a = 1 To 2
        For b = 1 To 2
            For c = 1 To 4 'Changed from 2 to 4
                For d = 1 To 4 'Changed from 2 to 4
                    For e = 1 To 4 'Changed from 2 to 4
                        For f = 1 To 4 'Changed from 2 to 4
                            i = i + 1
                            arr(i, 1) = grp(1, a)
                            arr(i, 2) = grp(2, b)
                            arr(i, 3) = grp(3, c)
                            arr(i, 4) = grp(4, d)
                            arr(i, 5) = grp(5, e)
                            arr(i, 6) = grp(6, f)
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2").Resize(1025, 6).Value = arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but I'd like to generate 6 columns out of ten. And each column (combination) will have only one of the two numbers in a group. since there are ten groups, so it should iterate though ten groups to generate 6 columns.

Comment: I would suggest you change four of the pairs to actually be sets of four. I will add a second version of the program to my answer.

Comment: I thought of this before, but it is not the same thing.

Comment: Ok I've got one more suggestion. I'll put it as a seperate answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments I think I better understand what you are looking for. It sounds like you want the combination to be a subset of six numbers from a set of ten. And each of those ten numbers is one of two values. If I understand that correctly, your issue is that you are having trouble iterating the six columns from the set of ten.

I replaced four of your For Loops with one that loops through the columns instead:

```
Sub Combs()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, e As Long, f As Long, alt As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr(1 To 1025, 1 To 6) As Long
    Dim grp() As Variant
    
    grp = Range("B1:c10").Value
    
    For a = 1 To 2
        For b = 1 To 2
            For c = 1 To 2
                For d = 1 To 2
                    For e = 1 To 2
                        For f = 1 To 2
                            For alt = 0 To 4
                            'Interating the used section through the full 10 columns.
                            'Only six columns are used in each combo, but we change which six are used from those 10
                                i = i + 1
                                arr(i, 1) = grp(1 + alt, a)
                                arr(i, 2) = grp(2 + alt, b)
                                arr(i, 3) = grp(3 + alt, c)
                                arr(i, 4) = grp(4 + alt, d)
                                arr(i, 5) = grp(5 + alt, e)
                                arr(i, 6) = grp(6 + alt, f)
                            Next alt
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2").Resize(1025, 6).Value = arr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Data]

Note: This produces 320 unique combinations. This is not all possible combinations with these number pairs, for a more complete list, you could add in additional arrays with column positions swapped.